# Sidekiq change params or argument

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I have been looking for the solution for this problem. I have tried to google it, could not find anything yet.

Problem:

I have this worker

```
class MailWorker
  def perform(user_id)
    user = User.find(user_id)
    ...
  end
end
```

that has been running for quite sometimes. And then, requirement change, we have to pass the reservation_id instead of user_id.

So the worker updated to:

```
class MailWorker
  def perform(reservation_id)
    reservation = Reservation.find(reservation_id)
    ....
  end
end
```

The problem is, if we push this code, some of the workers are already in Q. So, those workers will try to find the User but the new code is using Transaction.

What is the best approach for this? Do we have to create new Worker instead of use the existing one and delete the old once we are safe? Or there is a way to handle this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I would personally create a new Worker for this.

This makes it easier to handle all Jobs. (and is backwards compatible)